# query cache mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, caching

I would like to use query cache on MySQL, but my doubt is if I update or insert data on already cached query, will the cache reflect it?

Will it return only the cached query or the updated query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's query cache works automatically. You shouldn't have to worry about it becoming inconsistent like that.

In general terms, an update has the effect of invalidating any cached queries that would be affected.

Comment: Ok, I have static tables with 500000+ rows, Which ll be best? using memchached or query cache or change storage engine to memory (hash)

Comment: It really depends on the type of data you're fetching and how it's used. Memcached is a great general purpose cache and has the advantage of being able to cache the formatted results, not just the raw data. The MySQL query cache is easier to use, it's automatic, but less flexible. Most applications use Memcached to save blocks of HTML, XML or JSON to avoid formatting the same data repeatedly.

Comment: I am using select * from product; qry this product tbl ll static for long period, Now can you advise me ? which option ll be better for me. I prefer for both memory storage and qry cached for this qry... Is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

The query cache does not return stale data. When tables are modified, any relevant entries in the query cache are flushed.

Please refer doc for complete reference - [MySql Query Cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache.html)